# How to get currently held variant type, and define new variables of that type

Tags: c++, types, decltype, boost-variant, typeid

I have a `boost::variant` of types such as:

```
typedef boost::variant< uint8_t, int8_t, uint16_t, int16_t,
                uint32_t, int32_t, float, double, std::string > StorageTt;
```

A `StorageTt` variable, say `val`, is set to one of these storage types later in my code. I'd like to retrieve the type that `val` currently holds to define more variables of that same type. So if `val` is currently a `uint16_t`, I want to do something like:

```
typedef decltype(typeid(val)) StorageTt;
StorageTt new_val = 42;  // new_val should be a uint16_t
```

but this yields a `const type_info` type. I know I can do:

```
switch (val.which()) {
    case 0: // uint8_t
    case 1: //...
```

but I'd rather avoid the long switch-statement, because I have to do this multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using a visitor functor with a call operator template:

```
struct MyVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    template <typename StorageT>
    void operator()(const StorageT&) const
    {
        StorageT new_val = 32; // declare variable with same type

        doSomethingWith(new_val); // do something with it
    }
};
```

Apply it to the variant `val` like so:

```
boost::apply_visitor(MyVisitor(), val);
```

Reference:

- [`boost::variant` Basic Usage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic)
- [`boost::apply_visitor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html)
- [`boost::static_visitor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html)

I'm not aware of a way to replace the functor with a C++14 generic lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. Variables are syntactic constructs. They are names for program objects. Names only exist in the source code.

The workflow is as follows. First you write the source. Then you compile it, run the program, and it executes some actions, for example, retrieves a value from a `boost::variant` object. At this point you cannot define any names. There are no source, no names, no syntax. There are only objects.

If you need a new object of the same type as the one retrieved from the variant, then `StorageT new_val(val);` creates just that (the new object is hidden in `new_val`, you access it with `boost::get` or `boost::apply_visitor` or whatever).

If you want to perform an action on whatever variant you've got, and all actions *look* the same and only their types are different (they *are not* the same because the types are different, they just *look* the same), and you want to avoid writing same-looking stuff multiple times, then of course templates are your friends. `boost::apply_visitor` with a `template<typename> operator()` is the right one:

```
struct my_assignment_visitor: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    template <typename T> void operator()(T & var, double val) const
    {
        var = val;
    }
};

boost::apply_visitor(my_assignment_visitor(), new_val, 32.0);
```

Comment: Sweet! The type T gives me the type I'm looking for (uint16_t, double, etc), and I can define new variables using that.

Thanks again!

Comment: You are defining all possible variables at once at compile time, not one at a time as new types are encountered at run time. But if it works for you, great.

Answer (score 0):

Using the copy constructor should work:

```
// construct object of same type as val
StorageT new_val(val);
boost::get(new_val) = 32.0;
```

Comment: "How to get currently held variant type, and define new variables **of that type**"

Comment: According to the code sample in the question, he asked for a variant of the same type and the copy constructor does just that.

Comment: no, by assigning `32.0` to `new_val` you are changing its held type into `double`, and OP asks for `uint16_t` (which is not possible fyi).